What’s the name for this concept?
I remember a long time ago seeing a video talking about how if you’re trying to change a persons position on something, if you go past the persons something then the conversation is basically over and you have no hope of changing the persons mind.  I can’t remember the name of that something and forgot how to re-find the video.  Basically what it said as I remember is that saying certain things that were in someone’s something then from their point of view you look like someone who’s really extreme so that they will no longer wish to talk to you.  For instance as I remember I think he might have mentioned that if you tell a Young Earth Creationist that God doesn’t exist then you can basically forget about trying to convince them that Earth isn’t 6,000 years old because they won’t listen to other points you have, or if you tell a Jehovahs Witness that their religion is wrong then you crossed their something and so you can forget about trying to change their opinion on anything else.
Does anyone know the name of this something, in which if you cross it then you basically lose hope of changing their position on what you’re talking about?
